# How to change the value of a random subset of elements in a matrix without using a loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm currently attempting to select a subset of 0's in a very large matrix (about 400x300 elements) and change their value to 1. I am able to do this, but it requires using a loop where each instance it selects the next value in a randperm vector. In other words, 50% of the 0's in the matrix are randomly selected, one-at-a-time, and changed to 1:

```
z=1;
for z=1:(.5*numberofzeroes)
    A(zeroposition(rpnumberofzeroes(z),1),zeroposition(rpnumberofzeroes(z),2))=1;

    z=z+1;
end
```

Where 'A' is the matrix, 'zeroposition' is a 2-column-wide matrix with the positions of the 0's in the matrix (the "coordinates" if you like), and 'rpnumberofzeros' is a randperm vector from 1 to the number of zeroes in the matrix.

So for example, for z=20, the code might be something like this:

A(3557,2684)=1;

...so that the 0 which appears in this location within A will now be a 1.

It performs this loop thousands of times, because .5*numberofzeroes is a very big number. This inevitably takes a long time, so my question is can this be done without using a loop? Or at least, in some way that takes less processing resources/time?

As I said, the only thing that needs to be done is an entirely random selection of 50% (or whatever proportion) of the 0's changed to 1.

Thanks in advance for the help, and let me know if I can clear anything up! I'm new here, so apologies in advance if I've made any faux pa's.

Answer (score 0):

That's very easy.  I'd like to introduce you to my friend [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).  `sub2ind` allows you to take row and column coordinates of a matrix and convert them into linear column-major indices so that you can access multiple values in a matrix simultaneously in a single call.  As such, the equivalent code you want is:

```
%// First access the values in rpnumberofzeroes
vals = rpnumberofzeroes(1:0.5*numberofzeroes, :);

%// Now, use the columns of these to determine which rows and columns we want
%// to access A
rows = zeroposition(vals(:,1), 1);
cols = zeroposition(vals(:,2), 2);

%// Get linear indices via sub2ind
ind1 = sub2ind(size(A), rows, cols);

%// Now set these locations to 1
A(ind1) = 1;
```

The first statement gets the first half of your matrix of coordinates stored in `rpnumberofzeroes`.  The first column is the row coordinates, the second column is the column coordinates.  Notice that in your code, you wish to use the values in `zeroposition` to access the locations in `A`.  As such, extract out the corresponding rows and columns from `rpnumberofzeroes` to figure out the right rows and columns from `zeroposition`.  Once that's done, we wish to use these new rows and columns from `zeroposition` and index into `A`.  `sub2ind` requires three inputs - the size of the matrix you are trying to access... so in our case, that's `A`, the row coordinates and the column coordinates.  The output is a set of column major indices that are computed for each row and column pair.

The last piece of the puzzle is to use these to index into `A` and set the locations to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with linear indexing as well:

```
% find linear position of all zeros in matrix 
ix=find(abs(A)<eps);  
% set one half of those, selected at random, to one.
A(ix(randperm(round(numel(ix)*.5)))=1;
```